# Ubuntu 20.04 Only has one choice for Display Resolution

Tags: 20.04

I only have one choice for resolutions in Ubuntu 20.04
I am running on hardware - a modern intel NUC with inbuilt Graphics. Nothing Fancy.
I would like to change my Resolution. How?

**sudo lshw -c video**

```
*-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=1920x1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:177 memory:6022000000-6022ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

**xrandr**

```
Screen 0: minimum 256 x 256, current 2560 x 1440, maximum 16384 x 16384
rdp0 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   2560x1440     50.00*
```

Kind Regards, Mark Wardell